# Trigger onSwipe() motion layout only when specific view is in touch

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-motionlayout

I'm using motion layout to drag up and down a panel , it does work fine but the onSwipe() is working on the whole screen whereas i want it only to be sliding up and down when using specific view or dragging it . anyone could help ? Thank you in advance

- This my start layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/init_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e6ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Initializing..."
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/avatar_root"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#7A7878"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_share"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@null"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:contentDescription="btn_share" />

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/video_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/avatar_play"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_avatar_play"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_bg"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_back"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="button_back"
            android:onClick="goBackPressed"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/back_btn"
            app:tint="@color/white" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/save_anim"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:onClick="onSaveAnimation"
                android:text="Save"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/done_anim"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:onClick="onDoneAnimation"
                android:text="Done"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="btn_settings"
            android:hint="btn_settings"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/button_settings"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:tint="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:text="@string/saving_to_gallery"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="60dp"
            android:paddingLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
             />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_mute"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_mute" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_play"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_btn_play"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_reset"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/reset_button"
            app:tint="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/avatar_root"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_record"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="btn_record"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/record_button"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="88dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="@string/audio_duration_txt"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/custom_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:visibility="visible">
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/curvy_layout"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/line_shape"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

- This is my end layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/init_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e6ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Initializing..."
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/avatar_root"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#7A7878"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_share"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@null"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:contentDescription="btn_share" />

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/video_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/avatar_play"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_avatar_play"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_bg"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_back"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="button_back"
            android:onClick="goBackPressed"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/back_btn"
            app:tint="@color/white" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/save_anim"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:onClick="onSaveAnimation"
                android:text="Save"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/done_anim"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:onClick="onDoneAnimation"
                android:text="Done"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="btn_settings"
            android:hint="btn_settings"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/button_settings"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:tint="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:text="@string/saving_to_gallery"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="60dp"
            android:paddingLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
             />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_mute"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_mute" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_play"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_btn_play"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_reset"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/reset_button"
            app:tint="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/avatar_root"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_record"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="btn_record"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/record_button"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="88dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="@string/audio_duration_txt"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/custom_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:visibility="visible">
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/curvy_layout"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/line_shape"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

- this is the view i want to use to slide up and down ( tried touchAnchor and touchRegionId , it completely disables the animation)

```
<View
               android:id="@+id/line"
               android:layout_width="50dp"
               android:layout_height="5dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
               android:background="@drawable/line_shape"
               android:layout_gravity="center|bottom" />
```

Comment: We got the `app:touchRegionId` attribute working for that on a question just the other day, but it was for a side drawer, and the setup was a bit different:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EYpqy0AzP-4zxlKoTaWFQklLHDn6-44h/view?usp=drivesdk. I'm not sure if I'm following how yours is set up, exactly.

Comment: @MikeM. mine is different , onClick works fine on that view but onSwipe no luck weird

Comment: Wait, the `<View>`s at the end of those layouts are the ones you want to drag? Are you sure that doesn't need to be a direct child of the `MotionLayout`? Also, the start and end sets usually don't need to be complete copies. You should be able to define most of that in the main layout, and then specify only those things that change in the start and end sets.

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah the view i want to drag is not a direct child of motion layout and that's why i think it is not working ..

Comment: I just got a chance to put your layouts into Android Studio. I had to substitute all the missing resources and such, but I think I see what you're doing now. It's a vertical sliding drawer on the bottom, yeah? I modified that previous example to move the drawer to the bottom, and to resize the main content on the slide, too: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EhCukZUHIV2Hx29HKeXCMTtLdVZRqcrW/view?usp=share_link. Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZv6u.gif. If anything, it might help to show how you could reorganize your layouts to cut down on repeated stuff.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you for your time and help , eventually as you said in your other comment that the view to be used for dragging should be direct view of motion layout and that was correct